# API "v2/user/register" gives error "unauthorized_client"

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway

I am using test account on https://stage.wepay.com/

I am facing issues when I use "v2/user/register" API when I call it, I am getting exception "client application does not have permission to create users" Please check attached two screen shots (Application.png and API_Call.png ) for the details.
My application is having full access but still I am getting this error.

Note: I am not getting this error on other API usage like create account, checkout

I am struggling with this since long. Please help me on this as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

v2 does not allow you to register users. You need to use the oAuth for v2 applications.